# Where can I get 'Fortify One-Handed' enchantments?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm trying to get majorly good item enchantments so I can disenchant it and to be specific I need it to improve my 'One-Handed' skill.

Answer (score 8):

The enchantment **Fortify One-Handed** can be found on *Gloves*, *Boots*, *Amulets*, and *Rings*. Your best bet for finding one in a timely manner (as I know of no disenchantable Fortify One-Handed items that are guaranteed to be in any one place) is probably to quick-travel between a few major cities and check with their shops for apparel that has the desired enchantment (Or just sleep/wait in a single city - the idea is get the shops to change inventory).

Whiterun is a particularly good destination for this as it has 5-8 shops that could sell an item enchanted with Fortify One-Handed:

- The Drunken Huntsman,
- Belethor's General Goods,
- Adrianne *and* Ulfberth of Warmaiden's,
- Eorlund at the Skyforge.

The two I'm not entirely confident about are the Jewelery stall in the marketplace (there isn't usually much inventory, and jewelry could contain a far greater number of enchantments) and the mage in Dragonsreach. Additionaly, if you have a spouse staying in Breezehome, they might be an additional store to check out.

Keep in mind you do not need to *find* a good buff percent on the enchanted item, when you disenchant it, you just get the base effect. The numbers on stuff you enchant are determined by the size of the soul used, your Enchanting Skill, the enchanting perks you take as you level up, and any potions that boost enchanting you may or may not have used.

Answer (score 0):

If you are early in the game and do not have money to spare at a shop on enchanted weapons you can hit up some of the small bandit camps and hope the leveled equipment you get has the enchantment you want.  Or if you do not mind 'cheating' you can look up how to find one of the glitch chests, the one in Dawnstar is particularly good for enchantments.

There is no sure fire way to get any specific normal enchantment.

Answer (score 0):

Cicero’s clown clothes will have the fortify one handed effect. You can head to the town he broke down in or if he’s returned to the dark brotherhood you can always try pickpocketing his gloves or whatever garment has the effect. Personally I’d wait until someone is selling the item in Whiterun, probably easier in the long run.